# How to control return Vs print (or any other function ) if a script running as module or stand alone

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have write down a script that can be usable as both stand alone application or as a module that can be imported by another script. I have three function along with the main (a dummy code bellow explains my original condition):

## script_first.py

```
def add(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return c

def mult(a,b):
    c = a*b
    return c

def main():

   d =  mult(4,5)
   e = add(4,5)
   print d,e
   return d,e

if __name__=="__main__":

    main()
```

## script_second.py

```
import script_first
script_first.main()
```

Now if i run "script_first.py" or with "script_second.py" it return and print similar result.

My problem is that i want to do either "print d,e" if it runs as a stand alone script or " return d, e" if "script_first.py" runs from another script like "script_second.py"

how can i achieve this...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could see if it is called by a module or standalone using `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement and add a check variable to check if to print or not

```
def add(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return c

def mult(a,b):
    c = a*b
    return c

def main(Check=False):
    d =  mult(4,5)
    e = add(4,5)
    if Check:
        print d,e
    else:
        return d,e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TO_PRINT = True
    dag=main(TO_PRINT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want to *not return* some of the time. Having different behaviors (like returning or not) at different times can make things very confusing when it comes time to debug problems later on.

If you don't want the results to be printed when it's run from another module, move the `print` statement out of the function and into the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block (that is, `print` the `return`ed values):

```
def main():
   d =  mult(4,5)
   e = add(4,5)
   return d,e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print main()
```

This doesn't quite do the right thing though, you'll get parentheses around the values printed, because the return value is a tuple and `print (x, y)` is not the same thing as `print x, y` in Python 2 (the comma doesn't really make a tuple in the second version, it's more magical).

Fixing this issue is a bit awkward. It's much easier in Python 3, where `print` is a function and you can unpack the returned tuple as you are calling it. If you're using a recent version of Python 2, you can get the nicer Python 3 behavior by putting `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your module:

```
from __future__ import print_function

# function definitions as before

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(*main())
```

The `*` says "Unpack the results returned from `main()` as separate arguments to `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You have already half done the work by using `__name__ = '__main__'` .

The `__name__` variable will be set to `'__main__'` only when the script is run standalone, the `__name__` would be set to module name, when the script gets imported in another script.

What you can do for you case is to maybe define two different functions, one which returns d,e and another which just prints it.

Call the one that prints inside the `if __name__ = '__main__':` block, if you want to be extra secure you can define the function only inside that block, so that when its imported as a script, the function to print is not even available.

Example -

```
def add(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return c

def mult(a,b):
    c = a*b
    return c

def main():
   d =  mult(4,5)
   e = add(4,5)
   return d,e

if __name__=="__main__":
    def _main():
        d, e = main()
        print d, e
    _main()
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>python a.py
20 9

>>python
>>> import a
>>> a._main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_main'

>>> a.main()
(20, 9)
```